# Query to generate failed and not appeared for exam

Tags: sql, teradata

Let us say we have tables Student , Subject and Marks Tables.

The structure and data as below

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE tmp_work_db.student ,FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
     student_id     integer,  
  student_name      varchar(50) 

       )
PRIMARY INDEX  ( student_id );

insert into tmp_work_db.student
values(1,'Tim');
insert into tmp_work_db.student
values(2,'John');
insert into tmp_work_db.student
values(3,'Roy');


CREATE MULTISET TABLE tmp_work_db.subject ,FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
     subject_id     integer,  
  subject_name      varchar(50) 

       )
PRIMARY INDEX  ( subject_id );

insert into tmp_work_db.subject
values(1,'English');
insert into tmp_work_db.subject
values(2,'Maths');
insert into tmp_work_db.subject
values(3,'Hindi');


CREATE MULTISET TABLE tmp_work_db.marks ,FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
     student_id     integer, 
     subject_id     integer,  
     marks      integer 

       )
PRIMARY INDEX  ( student_id,subject_id );


insert into tmp_work_db.marks 
values(1,1,50);
insert into tmp_work_db.marks 
values(1,2,100);
insert into tmp_work_db.marks 
values(1,3,40);

insert into tmp_work_db.marks 
values(2,1,50);
insert into tmp_work_db.marks 
values(2,2,30);
```

We need to write a query which will generate a report with students who are failed in a particular subject and who not appeared for subject.

I tried below query to get students who are failed in a particular subjects

```
sel student_name,subject_name,marks from tmp_work_db.student st 
inner join
(
sel student_id,subject_id,marks from tmp_work_db.marks where marks < 35
) mrk
on st.student_id=mrk.student_id
inner join tmp_work_db.subject sub
on sub.subject_id=mrk.subject_id;
```

I am not able to get students who are not appeared in a particular subjects.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Nice overall question for the first one. I guess you're using teradata, pls add that as a tag to your question if that's the case. This also attracts more users familiar with this dbms. Is `sel column from table` valid sql?

Comment: if you replace words `sel` with `select`, then you'll get one row with `student_name ->John, subject_name->Maths, marks-> 30` isn't this you want?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is non-standard SQL, e.g. there is no `sel` in standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is the student names who have not marks for any of the subjects then you need a `cross join` between `student` and `subject` and a `left join` to `marks`:

```
select s.student_name, t.subject_name not_appeared
from student s cross join subject t 
left join marks m 
on m.student_id = s.student_id and m.subject_id = t.subject_id
where m.student_id is null
```

For the students that failed join the 3 tables and put the condition `marks < 35` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select s.student_name, t.subject_name failed
from student s 
inner join marks m on m.student_id = s.student_id
inner join subject t on m.subject_id = t.subject_id
where m.marks < 35
```

You can combine the 2 queries in one:

```
select  
  s.student_name, t.subject_name,
  case when m.marks is null then 'not appeared' else 'failed' end result
from student s cross join subject t 
left join marks m 
on m.student_id = s.student_id and m.subject_id = t.subject_id
where coalesce(m.marks, 0) < 35
order by s.student_name, t.subject_name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a1ad7067b9a14d91e7592151f10c02b1).
Results:

```
> student_name | not_appeared
> :----------- | :-----------
> John         | Hindi       
> Roy          | English     
> Roy          | Maths       
> Roy          | Hindi       

> student_name | failed
> :----------- | :-----
> John         | Maths
```

For the combined query:

```
> student_name | subject_name | result      
> :----------- | :----------- | :-----------
> John         | Hindi        | not appeared
> John         | Maths        | failed      
> Roy          | English      | not appeared
> Roy          | Hindi        | not appeared
> Roy          | Maths        | not appeared
```

Comment: Thanks for providing perfect queries.

Comment: Instead of `where coalesce(m.marks, 0) < 35` I would suggest an explicit `where m.marks < 35
   or m.marks IS NULL`, might be a bit easier to understand the logic :-)